# Troubleshooting Apache virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, troubleshooting, forbidden

Got some trouble using this configurations :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin **************
    ServerName nagios.vdb.local
    ServerAlias nagios

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/nagios/share

    ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/nagios/logs/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/nagios/logs/access.log combined

    ServerSignature Off

    ###################
    ###  CONFIG NAGIOS  ###
    ##################

    ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"

    <Directory "/usr/local/nagios/sbin">
       Options ExecCGI
       AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 10.1.1.0/24

       AuthBasicProvider ldap
       AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
       AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.1.1.*****************?sAMAccountName?sub?(memberOf=**************)
       AuthLDAPBindDN cn=A***********
       AuthLDAPBindPassword ***********
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Nagios Access LDAP"
       Require valid-user
    </Directory>

    Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"
    Alias /massAck "/usr/local/nagios/share/NagiosPlus/massAckTool/massAck.php"

    <Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share">
       Options None
       DirectoryIndex index.php
       AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 10.1.1.0/24

       AuthBasicProvider ldap
       AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
       AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.1.1.**************?sAMAccountName?sub?(memberOf=************)
       AuthLDAPBindDN cn=A*************
       AuthLDAPBindPassword ************
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Nagios Access LDAP"
       Require valid-user
    </Directory>

    ###################
    ###    CONFIG NRDP    ###
    ##################

    Alias /nrdp "/usr/local/nrdp"

    <Directory "/usr/local/nrdp">
    #  SSLRequireSSL
       Options None
       AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from 10.1.1.0/24

       AuthBasicProvider ldap
       AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
       AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.1.1.************?sAMAccountName?sub?(memberOf=***********)
       AuthLDAPBindDN cn=A************
       AuthLDAPBindPassword *********
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Nagios Access LDAP"
       Require valid-user
    </Directory>

    #####################
    ### CONFIG Nagiosgraph ###
    ###################

    # enable nagiosgraph CSS and JavaScript
    Alias /nagiosgraph "/usr/local/nagiosgraph/share"

    ScriptAlias /nagiosgraph/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagiosgraph/cgi"
    <Directory "/usr/local/nagiosgraph/cgi">
       Options ExecCGI
       AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 10.1.1.0/24
       AuthBasicProvider ldap
       AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
       AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.1.1.**********?sAMAccountName?sub?(memberOf=**********)
       AuthLDAPBindDN cn=A*******
       AuthLDAPBindPassword **********
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Nagios Access LDAP"
       Require valid-user
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/usr/local/nagiosgraph/share">
       Options None
       AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 10.1.1.0/24
    </Directory>

    ##################
    ###    CONFIG Cacti   ###
    #################

    Alias /cacti /usr/local/cacti/

    <Directory "/usr/local/cacti/">
        Options Indexes
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Options
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 10.1.1.0/24
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/local/cacti/plugins/weathermap>
        <Files editor.php>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 10.1.1.232
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    ##################
    ###    CONFIG GLPI   ###
    #################

    Alias /glpi /usr/local/glpi/
    <Directory "/usr/local/glpi">
        Options None
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Options
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 10.1.1.0/24
    </Directory>

    ####################
    ###    CONFIG VSHELL   ###
    ##################

    Alias /vshell2 "/usr/local/vshell2"

    <Directory "/usr/local/vshell2">
       Options None
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 10.1.1.0/24

       AuthBasicProvider ldap
       AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
       AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.1.1.******?sAMAccountName?sub?(memberOf=*************)
       AuthLDAPBindDN cn=Ap***********
       AuthLDAPBindPassword *******
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Nagios Access LDAP"
       Require valid-user
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My ip is 10.1.1.132 so normally, i have to got acces to anything in this virtualhost. I've deactivated too other configuration, so insted the main httpd.conf, nothing have to mismatch. But i got these trouble:

- When restarting apache, got a message :

`Starting httpd: [Wed Jun 01 10:35:40 2016] [warn] The ScriptAlias directive in /etc/httpd/vhosts.d/nagios.vdb.local.conf at line 104 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.`

It's this line :

```
ScriptAlias /nagiosgraph/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagiosgraph/cgi"
```

It's the first time i've loaded it, because i used it in the conf.d directory, that i've disabled by commenting the line `Include conf.d/*.conf` in the httpd.conf...

-Accessing nagios.vdb.local, got a DNS Error --> So **i'll use the server IP instead**, for prod purpose

- Accessing /nagios : Everything seems to be good, even if **CGI nedd a page reload to be accepted the first time**, and i don't understand why...
- Accessing /massAck : **got the code of the main page (it's .php)**, it will not be executed, so i probably missed a directive
- Accessing /nrdp : **forbidden access**
- Accessing /nagiosgraph : **forbidden access**
- Accessing /cacti : **got an index of the directory**.
- Accessing /glpi : **forbidden access**
- Accessing /vshell2 : i have the main page but it will not appear connected. Note that using alias without virtualhost, everything is good.

Is there a directive first to execute php in virtualhost ? And how to solve my forbidden access in virtualhost (who work using alias when not using virtualhost) ?

Answer (score 0):

My apache2 skills aren't excellent but maybe this will help:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

> First, all Redirects are processed before Aliases are processed, and therefore a request that matches a Redirect or RedirectMatch will never have Aliases applied. Second, the Aliases and Redirects are processed in the order they appear in the configuration files, with the first match taking precedence.
>
> For this reason, when two or more of these directives apply to the same sub-path, you must list the most specific path first in order for all the directives to have an effect. For example, the following configuration will work as expected:
>
> Alias "/foo/bar" "/baz"
> Alias "/foo" "/gaq"
>
> But if the above two directives were reversed in order, the /foo Alias would always match before the /foo/bar Alias, so the latter directive would be ignored.

Maybe you should try to swap the positions of

```
Alias /nagiosgraph "/usr/local/nagiosgraph/share"
ScriptAlias /nagiosgraph/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagiosgraph/cgi"
```

to

```
ScriptAlias /nagiosgraph/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagiosgraph/cgi"
Alias /nagiosgraph "/usr/local/nagiosgraph/share"
```

Hope this helps